# iPhone - is RSS / Reddit client a good project to introduce a student to Objective-C?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm thinking about a good way for an iOS developer to bring a programming student up to speed with iOS development. Such student already knows programming in some language, but not necessarily objective-c. Up to date, I've seen a number of projects that use networking used for this purpose:

- RSS readers
- Reddit or similar API clients that parse JSON
- Photo gallery

Personally, I think such projects are a bit too heavy for a student, as they may involve asynchronous communication, blocks and networking. As far as I understand, such projects are used because they provide content (titles, descriptions, image URLs), removing the need for an iOS developer to create own content.

**Is there a simpler project that can be given to a student programmer to bring them up to speed with iOS development?**

Comment: With AFNetworking, I'd argue that asynchronous communication has become quite easy. Success and failure blocks are quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

We've been giving similar tasks to our students. I think it really depends on how much time do they have for the task. You can take a look at [**CS193P**](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) tasks for **Stanford students**. They are usually meant for 1 week.

**It also depends if you want them to produce a working project or it is just meant as an exercise.**

If you want to avoid these tasks, then you might give your students a smaller project using Core Data or mostly buttons. There are number of options for a project like this:

- Calculator
- Clock app
- Email client (without networking)
- Text editor
- Weather app (without design)
- And many more...

*There are also options for you to divide a single project into more exercises, to make it easier and force students to learn and work on specific topic, such as blocks, delegation or similar.*